# angularjs doesn't work in an Android WebView when loadDataWithBaseURL is used with file://

Tags: android, angularjs, android-webview

If html/javascript is loaded using loadDataWithBaseURL, with the base url set to a local file location then functions such as $http.get will cause an exception "SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18"

This occurs in angular.js when trying to access document.cookie - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125196/when-using-loaddatawithbaseurl-an-exception-occurs-when-trying-to-get-or-set-coo

I've hacked angular.js to catch this exception, but I'm hoping someone has a better solution.